# Boxing process of value type fields embedded in a reference type

Tags: c#, clr, boxing

I am currently learning c#. Trying to clarify some questions regarding boxing.

Consider this example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public sealed class Program
{

    public int value = 0;  

    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Program();

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p.value);
    }

}
```

That is the signature of theSerializeObject method:

```
public static string SerializeObject(object? value)
```

As you can see the method I use in the example requires reference to the object as a parameter, but I am passing value type instead.
I suppose that boxing must occur here. But the value field I am accessing is already allocated on a managed heap, since it is embedded field of a reference type.

The questions are:

a) Since it is obvious that local variable would get boxed in that situation (being passed as a   parameter to SereializeObject()) what would happen to field access (p.value) in the example? Would the p.value be transformed into local variable and allocated on a thread stack and then get boxed?

b) What would happen if the field "value" was static? Would it get boxed?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public sealed class Program
{

    public static int value = 0;  

    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Program();

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, value is a field of an object and stored on the GC heap, but it is not an object itself.  It doesn't have the object header, cannot independently live outside of the Program object and occupies a mere 4 bytes of storage.  Which is why boxing is necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is value type boxing when it is a field of reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658628/is-value-type-boxing-when-it-is-a-field-of-reference-type)