# How to handle any property type/value within an expression holder without boxing in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Lets assume I have an employee class as follow:

```
var employee = new Employee
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Smith",
    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now
};
```

To define an expression for a given property, I wrote something like this:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, string>> expression = e => e.FirstName;
```

This is fine for string type but if I want generalize this operation (extracting specified property value through an extension method). I have defined a general expression holder and then process it at given time. As a result, I have to define this expression as follow:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, object>> expressionHolder { get; set; }
```

Because I may target non-reference type property (like DateTime). Is it possible to avoid this boxing for this holder?

Comment: It hugely depends on how `expressionHolder ` will be used.

Comment: Could you show us said extension method?

Comment: I think a "why" is helpful here. x/y problem? What are you solving that you need this for?

Comment: What makes you think there will be boxing here?

Comment: Expression trees and lambdas on their own are much more costly than boxing an argument is. You may well be focusing on optimizing the wrong thing, assuming of course it needs optimizing at all, which is by no means a given.

Comment: Due object definition above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658628/is-value-type-boxing-when-it-is-a-field-of-reference-type

Comment: If I can determine the type/value for the specified property, then I can check if property value match the default value. In this case I need to know in advance the type I am dealing with for this check to work. Is a string, int, float ...etc (Reference/Value/Custom)

Comment: There is no boxing happening in expression trees as you don't actually provide any values to it or get any results from it directly. It is not executed in C# anyways unless `.Compile().Invoke()` is explicitly called, but you should use a plain `Func` instead in that case

Comment: It is common to use _generics_, i.e. declare a type parameter (say `TProperty`) on a containing type. Then you can have `Expression<Func<Employee, TProperty>>`.

Comment: Why are you using `Expression`? Are you trying to use this with EF? Consider: `expressionHolder` can only have one static type - it can't have both `Expression<Func<Employee,string>>` and `Expression<Func<Employee,int>>`. Depending on how you intend to use it, `Expression` or `LambdaExpression` could be possibilities, otherwise you have a static/runtime conflict and must decide which you need.