# Does a value type property in a reference type contain boxed value?

Tags: c#

Lets say we have a type:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int intProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

What will happen when I pass the property in a method like this?

```
var obj = new SomeClass();
obj.intProperty = 1;

SomeMethod(obj.intProperty);

public void SomeMethod(int value) { ... }
```

Will the passing of intProperty copy the value from the property like value types usually do?

Comment: inside of the function , it will send a copy because the function SomeMethod takes an integer it do not know anything about the class object. 

so its going to byVal call

Comment: Yes, if there is no ref, in or out modifier in the method signature the value is just passed byval, I e. copied. Be it a variable field or property.It be boxed if the method expects a reference type, eg. object.

Comment: I don't see anything in the body of this question that would appear to relate to boxing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is value type boxing when it is a field of reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658628/is-value-type-boxing-when-it-is-a-field-of-reference-type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### Does a value type property in a reference type contain boxed value?

No, it contains the value (`int`) itself (at least in current C# implementations I know of). If you want to dive deeper into the CLR implementation details check out [Managed object internals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/) article series:

> The layout of a managed object is pretty simple: a managed object contains instance data, a pointer to a meta-data (a.k.a. method table pointer) and a bag of internal information also known as an object header.

[image]

##### What will happen when I pass the property in a method like this?

The value of `SomeClass.intProperty` (via getter call) will be copied and passed as parameter to `SomeMethod` call.

##### Will the passing of intProperty copy the value from the property like value types usually do?

Yes. If your concern is that the `SomeMethod` can somehow change the value of the `SomeClass.intProperty` - then no, it can't (though it has nothing to do with boxing/unboxing):

```
SomeMethod(obj.intProperty);
Console.WriteLine(obj.intProperty);// Prints "1"

void SomeMethod(int value) 
{  
    value = 42;
    Console.WriteLine(value); // Prints "42"
}
```

P.S.

I highly recommend to follow [standard naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names), i.e. Pascal case for properties here - `SomeClass.intProperty` -> `SomeClass.IntProperty`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will copy the property like value types.

Your code can be rewritten as below, and as you can see - it is being copied/passed as value type.

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
obj.intProperty = 1;

int propertyValue = obj.intProperty;             
SomeMethod(propertyValue);
```